# Can I use an SSL socket using a certificate that is not a file on disk? (ie. in the database)

Tags: php, sockets, ssl, stream, push-notification

I am trying to connect via an SSL socket to a remote server (ITunes Push service, but that's pretty irrelevant).

I have it working using `stream_context_set_option($context, 'ssl', 'local_cert', $pemFile);` where $pemFile is the location of a local .pem file. But, as the software will be managing many accounts each with their own certificate I would like to store the certificates in the database to ease management.

So, my question is: Is there a way to use the certificate content directly instead of pointing to a file in the file system?

(I am using the PHP5.2, Zend Framework if there are any tools in there to help)

Comment: Write it out to tmpfile() and use that?

Comment: I'd rather not have to, but that is an option

Comment: Yotaware, that's the only viable option I've found. Make it an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't appear that there is a way to use a string as the certificate. The only option seems to be to write the file to disk temporarily, using [tmpfile()](http://php.net/tmpfile) or similar and use that.